# FastAPI: Problem with automatic creation of tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, fastapi

I learn fastAPI framework, and need to change sqlite engine to mysql engine, what I've done:

database.py:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

DB_USER = 'user'
DB_PASSWORD = ''
DB_HOST = 'host'
DB_PORT = 'port'
DB_NAME = 'name'

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = f"mysql+mysqlconnector://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASSWORD}@{DB_HOST}:{DB_PORT}/{DB_NAME}"


engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL
)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()

def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

PS I used variables (DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, etc) as my password is empty string, and there was an error when I directly was writing everything in url without variables.

models.py:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, DateTime
from ..database import Base

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    username = Column(String, unique=True)
    address = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)
    # createdAt = Column(DateTime)
```

The problem is that I have to manually create tables of db and respectfully the columns too (through phpmyadmin). Is there a way so that the tables are created automatically when I run the program as there are already created necessary models in models.py with all the necessary information.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Omg, I forgot to write `models.user.Base.metadata.create_all(database.engine)` in main.py, that's why the tables were not able to be created automatically.